# Constexpr строки, создание из C-Style строки

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

Сначала дам собственно код:

```
#define X_ASSERT(CHECK) \
( (CHECK) ? void(0) : []{assert(!#CHECK);}() )    

template <int N, typename CharT>
class string_literal {
    static_assert(N >= 0, "Empty size parametr 'N'!");
    const CharT(&_lit)[N + 1];

public:
    constexpr string_literal(const CharT(&lit)[N + 1])
        :
        _lit((X_ASSERT(lit[N] == CharT('\0')), lit))
    {}

    using char_type = CharT;

    constexpr CharT operator[](int i) const {
        return X_ASSERT(i >= 0 && i < N), _lit[i];
    }
    constexpr std::size_t size() const { return N; }
    constexpr const CharT* c_str() const { return _lit; }
    constexpr operator const CharT*() const { return c_str(); }
    constexpr operator std::basic_string_view<CharT>() const { return { c_str(), size() }; }
};

template <typename CharT>
constexpr int inline str_size(const CharT* str, int size = 0) {
    return (str[0] == CharT('\0')) ? size : str_size(str + 1, size + 1);
}

template <int N, typename CharT>
constexpr decltype(auto) inline literal(const CharT(&lit)[N])
{
    return string_literal<N - 1, CharT>(lit);
}
```

Вопрос такой код работает:

```
constexpr auto NAME = simplelogger::utils::literal("NAME");
constexpr auto name = "NAME";
constexpr const char(&ch)[4] = { name[0], name[1] , name[2], name[3]};
```

но если я добавляю конструктор и функцию для получения строки из с-style:

```
template <int ...PACK>
constexpr string_literal(const CharT* str, std::integer_sequence<int, PACK...>) 
    :
    _lit{str[PACK]...}
{}

template <int N, typename CharT>
constexpr decltype(auto) inline literal_b(const CharT* str) {
    return string_literal<N, CharT>(str, std::make_integer_sequence<int, N>{});
}
```

и создаю таким путем:

```
constexpr auto var = "VAR";
constexpr auto var_2 = simplelogger::utils::literal_b<simplelogger::utils::str_size(var)>(var); // Должно сработать
```

то компилятор выводит следующее:

```
Source.cpp
1>source.cpp(36): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant 
1>stringliteral.hpp(26): note: failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime
1>stringliteral.hpp(26): note: see usage of '$S2'
```

Все Note относятся к строке инициализации `_lit{str[PACK]...}` в новом конструкторе. Как мне реализовать создание string_literal из указателя на с-строку. Компилятор MSVC 2017 последней версии (С++17 включен).

**ADD:** Может проще тогда сделать не `const CharT[&lit][N + 1]`, а `CharT lit[N + 1]`. Проще использовать, но вроде как произойдет копирование, а не сохранение исходных символов? (Просто хотелка)

Answer (score 1):

Непонятно, чем вам `::std::string_view` не угодил:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

constexpr ::std::string_view const lit1{"Literal1"};
constexpr auto const psz_literal{"Literal2"};
constexpr ::std::string_view const lit2{psz_literal};

int main()
{
    ::std::cout << lit1.data() << ::std::endl;
    ::std::cout << lit2.data() << ::std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YI9KS6l0qBoBwSh9)

Comment: Ну, хотелось изобрести свой велосипед с всеми возможностями. Да и не знал, что кроме constexpr-конструкторов у него все остальные методы тоже constexpr.

Comment: Отмечу ваш ответ, но хотелось бы взять ссылки на исходные символы, т.е. фактически взять во владение у `const char_type*` как это делает мой вариант.